# GeoJSON to SVG and utilize SVG in the same position as GeoJSON (coordinates)?

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, geojson

Maybe my question is complicated, but I wonder if I can use an SVG that was previously GeoJSON, in the same position in which the coordinates of the GeoJSON were offset? If so, how could I do it?

I try to do this with leaflet!

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: it's like trying to draw an SVG on top of the map, I couldn't find an example but the ImageOverlay (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#imageoverlay) method is very close to it, only I want to work it as SVG not as image

Comment: How you generate your svg from geoJSON?

Comment: What about https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#svgoverlay?

Comment: Late input but [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg) may help for in such cases.